# Localstorage setting through ajax data randomly gets undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am setting items to localstorage using the below code. The issue I am getting is whenever I refresh the page some of the items are not set when I inspect the localstorage it shows as undefined, this is absolutely random and sometimes all items are set parfectly. How can I ensure that all the items are set without any undefined?

```js
const catdata = [];
var catArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat'));

for (let i = 0; i < catArr.length; i++) {   

  const catid   = catArr[i]['id'];
  const catname = catArr[i]['name'];

  $('#topitems').prepend('<div ><a class="topitems" href="'+catArr[i]['id']+'">'+catArr[i]['name']+'</a></div>');  

  (function(i) {
    $.ajax( { url : "sales/item_search_cat?cat="+catid
            , data : "GET" 
            //  ,  async: "false",
            , dataType : "json"
            , success : function(data) {
                          catdata.push(data);
                          localStorage.setItem(catid,JSON.stringify(catdata[i]));
                        }
            });  
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: First what is undefined, is `catid` undefined or does `JSON.stringify(catdata[i])` return an `'undefined'` string?

Comment: edited to show where catid is coming from. .Yes it's sometimes and randomly returning undefined

Comment: **1)** In ALL success callbacks `catid` will be `catArr[catArr.length-1]['id']`. Because the loop ended and `i` reached the max value. **2)** You are setting **multiple times** a storage item with the value returned by `catArr[catArr.length-1]['id']` as a key... Not `"cat"`!

Comment: **3)** What are you really trying to do? Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the `ajax` requests are not sequentially executed, and sometimes your code is accessing an index that doesn't exist.

For example, one response arrives with index 2, the code pushes into the empty array at index 0, and `catdata[i]` is trying to get the index 2.

I think you have to call the ajax request using `await` or you can use the data directly:

```
localStorage.setItem(catid, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Possible solution (I didn't test it):
The execution is async, if you need to wait for the executions, you have to follow an async/await approach.

```
function callAjax(catid) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "sales/item_search_cat?cat=" + catid,
      data: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem(catid, JSON.stringify(data));
        success(data);
      }
    });
}

let catArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat'));
catArr.forEach(function({id: catid, name: catname}) {
  $('#topitems').prepend('<div ><a class="topitems" href="' + catid + '">' + catname + '</a></div>');
  callAjax(catid);
});
```

Comment: I checked with await but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @iglesas remember `$.ajax` doesn't return a promise, so you should modify the logic of your function to be able to use Promises.